# How to make composed_of value object update or re-create itself when its fields change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a rails-2.3 app that's using composed_of to create an Address class which knows how to geocode itself, among other things. This is all well and good, but given a loaded model that has an address, when I change the fields of which the address is composed on the model, the address instance neither changes nor re-creates itself automatically, and I'm afraid I can't figure out the cleanest way to forcibly make that happen.

The model code is straightforward:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  composed_of :address, :mapping => [%w(address1 address1), %w(address2 address2), %w(city city), %w(state state), %w(postal_code postal_code), %w(country_code country), %w(longitude lng), %w(latitude lat)]

end
```

Any suggestions?

I've subsequently answered this but cannot answer my own question already, so here goes:

It turns out that composed_of creates a reader method that has an (undocumented) force_reload parameter. I take advantage of that and create accessor methods for each of the composed fields:

```
  composed_of :address, :mapping => ADDRESS_MAPPING                                                      
  ADDRESS_MAPPING.each do |field, composed_field|                                                        
    next if %w(latitude longitude).include?(field)                                                       
    define_method "#{field}=" do |value|                                                                 
      self[field] = value                                                                                
      if send("#{field}_changed?")                                                                       
        self[:longitude] = nil                                                                           
        self[:latitude] = nil                                                                            
        address(true)                                                                                    
      end                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                  
  end
```

It's a bit hokey, but it works.

I might see about factoring this changed? check up into the based composed_of reader method.

Comment: just edited my answer, I like challenges ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could either `reload` your variable manually:

```
@my_variable.reload
```

or make it happen in an `after_save` callback (in your model as well).

EDIT:

You could do the following:

```
@my_variable.clear_aggregation_cache
```

(of course wrap it in a callback)

See module `ActiveRecord::Aggregations`

Comment: That's pretty inefficient though. It adds an unnecessary trip to the database just to recreate a value object composed of fields that are already there in memory. I'm sure I can do better than that.

Comment: Ok, let's find something better!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom converter then assign custom data to the :address attribute directly.